# Reset AutoInc counters with Slick database

Tags: database, scala, playframework, slick

After a `delete` on a table, the counter for `AutoInc` isn't reset back to 1.  This is the right behaviour, not disputing that, but I wonder if there is any way to reset the Slick `AutoInc` counter as well?

The only way I've found is to delete the entire database.

Comment: If you're interested to know why I want to do this, I have a set of data dumps that I'd like to quickly test, and they go out of sync if the `AutoInc` counters aren't controlled as well.

Comment: `forceInsertAll` with the primary key values is more work, it'd be easier to have `AutoInc` counters reset.

Comment: The only way I know to reset the AutoInc field on MySQL or postgres is via an alter table query. I don't think you can run generate an alter table query using slick. The only way I think is using plain SQL query in Slick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go here would be slick plain SQL and use a db specific SQL query to do it.

Comment: I note that you're in the Slick development team and so I'll certainly accept that as the answer. ;) Many thanks for taking the time to check SO and answer this question.

Comment: Thx and sorry for my brevity. Quite busy these days. Good luck to you.